# How to Download All JARs from Maven Public Repository

Tags: maven-2

I am interested in obtaining all JAR files contained in the public repository http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Is there a way to do so apart from writing a POM file containing all items in the Dependency section?

Essentially I want to create a local mirror

Comment: Have you found a way to download complete maven repos?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like - http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/ to mirror the entire repository but it is going to be huge.

I would recommend you use a local repository manager like:

- http://nexus.sonatype.org/
- http://archiva.apache.org

Answer (score 2):

Use a repo manager like Nexus. Trying to mirror everything will get you banned.